# Nuxtjs: Adding Vuejs plugins doesn't get initialized/ shown on my template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to add a vue-button-loading plugin to my project. I've installed the plugin properly and added the necessary configurations as instructed on nuxtjs on how to install the plugin.

Here is where I installed my plugin on nuxt.config.js file:

```
export default {
  ...
  plugins: [
      {
        src:'~/plugins/loading-button.js', mode: 'client'
      }
  ]
  ...
 }
```

And then I created loading-button.js under the plugins folder as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueLoadingButton from 'vue-loading-button'

Vue.use(VueLoadingButton)
```

Lastly, I load my button on the template with:

```
<VueLoadingButton />
```

But nothing seems to show. If I inspect I can see it is initialized.

Any help to resolve this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use `vue.component` instead

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueLoadingButton from 'vue-loading-button'

Vue.component('my-loading-button', VueLoadingButton)
```

and in your vue template

```
<my-loading-button :loading="true">Send</my-loading-button>
```

You can check live here
https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-bartik-43e37?file=/plugins/loading-button.js

Comment: Okay let me try

Comment: Hello @Sovai I've tried but am getting the error: [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <VueLoadingButton> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can try again. Please mark it as answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Hi @Sovai, thanks it works now. How can I trigger it to load on button click? as for now it shows loading icon always

Comment: hi @gxvr sorry for the late reply. you can check the demo in my answer above. I have updated the code

Comment: Hello @Sovai, no worries. Thanks it works perfectly now